# Calculate shopping cart total in XSLT 1.0 with recursion

Tags: xslt

I can't seem to find the error in my recursion. I was hoping you could give me a hand. I am trying to calculate the total price of items in a shopping cart but the code below produces a result much higher than expected.

Here is the XML:

```
<products>
    <entry id="123">
        <price>100</price>
    </entry>
    <entry id="456">
        <price>150</price>
    </entry>
</products>
<storage>
    <item id="123" count="2" />
    <item id="456" count="3" />
</storage>
```

And the XSLT:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="products/entry" />

<xsl:template match="products/entry">
    <xsl:param name="running-total" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="price" select="price" />
    <xsl:variable name="quantity" select="storage/item[@id = current()/@id]/@count" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::entry[1]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::entry[1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="running-total" select="$price * $quantity + $running-total"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$price * $quantity + $running-total"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks! I'd appreciate any tips on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: For the future: A complete question needs an error description, so people don't have to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion takes one `<entry>` at a time, you need to start it with the first one, instead of *all of them*. Doing

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="products/entry[1]" />
```

Gives the correct output:

```
650
```

Also, as @zx485 notes in the comments, this

```
<xsl:variable name="quantity" select="storage/item[@id = current()/@id]/@count" />
```

works in the context of the `<entry>`, so it can't work like that. Use an absolute path to like `/root/storage/item[...]` if you currently get `NaN` as your result.

Having said that, you can simplify your recursive template a bit:

```
<xsl:template match="products/entry">
    <xsl:param name="running-total" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="quantity" select="/root/storage/item[@id = current()/@id]/@count" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::entry[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="running-total" select="price * $quantity + $running-total"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::entry)">
        <xsl:value-of select="price * $quantity + $running-total"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

You could use an `<xsl:key>` for cleaner "quantity" lookups, too:

```
<xsl:key name="quantity" match="storage/item/@count" use="../@id" />

<xsl:template match="products/entry">
    <xsl:param name="running-total" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="total" select="price * key('quantity', @id) + $running-total" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::entry[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="running-total" select="$total"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::entry)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your `select="storage/item[@id...` is still in the context of `<entry>`, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @zx485 I know, I took the OP's code as it is, because I suspected the main error to be the `<xsl:apply-templates>`. I assumed they knew about that as well, and just have different XML. I'll make a note of that point in the answer, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved the problem: `<xsl:apply-templates select="products/entry[1]" />`. Yes, I am using the absolute path to get to the count. Thank you also for the tips!